# Permission denied error while creating file by using script file

Tags: bash, files, sudo, sh

I have created a script file called **black_list.sh**.

```
#!/bin/bash

default_card=`head -1 /proc/asound/modules`
echo $default_card

if [ ! -e /etc/modprobe.d/sound.blacklist.conf ] && [[ "$default_card" =~ "snd_hda_intel" ]]; then
        echo "blacklist snd_hda_intel" > /etc/modprobe.d/sound.blacklist.conf ---> not working            
else
        echo "Default sound card(snd_hda_intel) is already added in black list";
fi
```

from this script file I am creating **sound.blacklist.conf** file in `/etc/modprobe.d` but I got `/etc/modprobe.d/sound.blacklist.conf: Permission denied` error.

So tried

`echo itsme | sudo -S echo "blacklist snd_hda_intel" > /etc/modprobe.d/sound.blacklist.conf`

but it also not worked so how can create a file in `/etc/modprobe.d` directory from my **script file**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd personally use tee which you can run as root to append to files:

```
echo "blacklist snd_hda_intel" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/sound.blacklist.conf
```

But that might not be expected half-way through a script. If you're doing things that require root privileges, it might —and I'm not saying this for certain— make more sense to only let root run the script by sticking this near the top of the script:

```
if [[ $EUID -ne 0 ]]; then
  echo "Only root can run this. Run again with sudo" 2>&1
  exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this command,

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'blacklist snd_hda_intel' >  /etc/modprobe.d/sound.blacklist.conf"
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to enclose the output redirection into the `sudo` too.

The easiest way, for me, to do this is not to put the **sudo** inside your script, but to run your script using **sudo**.

To understand your problem, if you have the following command :
    $ sudo " "  > /etc/file

The **sudo** action is only to execute `<command> <params>`, the redirection of output (`>`) happens out of the **sudo** in this case.